# How to select certain columns by multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've made a dataframe from a dictionary to manipulate it.

```
dic_people = defaultdict(dict)

dic_people['A']['language']    = 'English'
dic_people['A']['nationality'] = 'Russia'
dic_people['A']['joined']      = 201010

dic_people['B']['language']    = 'French'
dic_people['B']['nationality'] = 'Canada'
dic_people['B']['joined']      = 201009

dic_people['C']['language']    = 'English'
dic_people['C']['nationality'] = 'Canada'
dic_people['C']['joined']      = 201008

dic_people['D']['language']    = 'French'
dic_people['D']['nationality'] = 'France'
dic_people['D']['joined']      = 201007

dic_people['E']['language']    = 'English'
dic_people['E']['nationality'] = 'Ireland'
dic_people['E']['joined']      = 201011

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_people)

>>> df
                A       B        C       D        E
joined        201010  201009   201008  201007   201011
language     English  French  English  French  English
nationality   Russia  Canada   Canada  France  Ireland
```

I want to select 2 people who 1) joined earliest and 2) speak English. So, the result will be

```
                A       C      
joined        201010  201008  
language     English  English 
nationality   Russia  Canada
```

I'd like to know how to do this. I tried `df[ df.loc['language'] == 'English']`, but it seems it's somewhat different when referring to rows, not columns.

Comment: What do you mean by joined earliest??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by rows and for first 2 column select by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
#if necessary sorting by 'joined' value in index
#df = df.sort_values('joined', axis=1)

df1 = df.loc[:,  df.loc['language'] == 'English'].iloc[:, :2]
print (df1)
                   A        C
language     English  English
nationality   Russia   Canada
joined        201010   201008
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!